# Finding the inverse and proving that the function is bijective

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Prove that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x)= x |x| +1
$$
is bijective and find the inverse.

---

This is what I did to prove that the function is one to one.

Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

Then $x_1 |x_1| +1=x_2 |x_2| +1$ or $x_1 |x_1| =x_2 |x_2|$

Case 1:  $x_1,x_2 \ge0$ or $x_1,x_2\le0$

Then  $x_1^2= x_2^2$.

Thus $x_1=x_2$ (As both  $x_1,x_2$ are of the same sign in this case)

Case 2: Suppose  $x_1>0$ and $x_2<0$:

Then $x_1 \cdot x_1=-k\cdot k$ where $x_2 =-k$ and $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Then $x_1^2 =-k^2$. This is not possible. So is the case with x$_2$>0 and x$_1$<0.

Hence either  $x_1,x_2\ge0$ or $x_1,x_2\le0$. In that case $x_1 =x_2$. Hence $f$ is one to one.

$y= x |x| +1$.

If $x\ge0$:

$y-1=x^2$

$x=\sqrt{y-1}$

If $x<0$:

$y-1=-x^2$

$x=\sqrt{1-y}$

Thus
$$f^{-1}=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x},  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
\sqrt{x-1}, & \text{if $x \ge0$}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

**Is this the correct inverse? How to show that $f$ is surjective? And is my proof of one to one correct?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your proof looks good. To prove surjectivity, we need to show that for all $y$ in the co-domain, there exists an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$. With the inverse that you have found with range  = $\mathbb{R}$ you have essentially showed surjectivity.

Comment: Oh. And spotted two slight mistakes. For the case $x<0$, $x$ should be $-\sqrt{1-y}$ instead. Next, for your inverse function, notice after making $x$ the subject we are interchanging $x$ and $y$ as dummy variables. In that case, the domain for your inverse function should be $x<1$ and $x\geq 1$ instead of $x<0$ and $x \geq 0$.

Comment: When x<0 it why should there be a minus sign?Is it because square root is positive and to get a negative value(as x<0), we have to have a minus sign?And can you explain how it becomes x<1 and x>=1.

Comment: Why does it say that if the function is one to one then an inverse exists. Shouldn't our function be a bijection in order to have a inverse?So if I have to prove a function is surjective is it enough to find the inverse and if the function's co-domain and the inverse function's domain are equal,can I say that the function is surjective.

Comment: (About the minus sign) Yes, the convention is for the square root symbol to denote the positive square root so we take the negative value as $x<0$. Notice that $y = x|x|+1$ so $y<1$ if $x<0$. (Similarly $y\geq 1$ if $x\geq0$). When we define $f^{-1}(x)$ the "$x$" is actually behaving as a dummy for "$y$".

Comment: And yes, finding an inverse function is another way to show bijection (both surjectivity and injectivity together). However, we have to be careful that we haven't just found an inverse relation: the inverse function has to be well-defined on the entire range of $f$. I will suggest still going through the usual procedure of showing surjectivity (given any $y$ in codomain, exhibit an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.) You'd be doing very similar procedures but the slight difference in emphasis is worth understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut:

Function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto x\left|x\right|$
has an inverse in $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$y\mapsto\sqrt{y}$ if $y\geq0$ and $y\mapsto\sqrt{-y}$ otherwise.
The existence of an inverse *garantees* the bijectivity of $g$ and
consequently of $f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)+1$.

If you are asked to prove bijectivity *and* to find an inverse then
in principle it is enough to do the second task only.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of injectivity is good, albeit a bit involved.

From $x_1|x_1|=x_2|x_2|$ you immediately deduce that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both positive, both negative or both $0$. So you can get $|x_1|^2=|x_2|^2$ from which $|x_1|=|x_2|$ and the conclusion is immediate.

For surjectivity, you have to work a bit harder. If $y=x|x|+1$, then $x|x|=y-1$.

So, for $y>1$ you have to find $x>0$, for $y=1$ you can take $x=0$ and for $y<1$ you have to take $x<0$.

If $y>1$, the condition becomes “$x^2=y-1$ and $x>0$”, so $x=\sqrt{y-1}$.

If $y<1$, …